Trying to understand output of p-states (amdgpu)
Currently i'm trying to understand how GPU Overclocking (RX6600) works under linux. I read the Arch Wiki about amdgpu and made some "discoveries" i don't really understand.
For example if i try to read my GPU Frequency with:
$ cat /sys/class/drm/card0/device/pp_dpm_sclk

0: 0Mhz*
1: 0Mhz*

however if i instead use sudo i get
# cat /sys/class/drm/card0/device/pp_dpm_sclk
 
0: 500Mhz
1: 800Mhz*
2: 2750Mhz

So my first question would be why is the output different when using sudo? I didn't even know something like this was possible and thought it either is able to read or it needs sudo.
My second question would be. Why does the second output have a * on 800Mhz which i guess is indicating it currently is using that clockspeed/pstate? When it actually isn't (the actual current clockrate is much lower and isn't even reaching 500Mhz at this point).
